# Javascript: Draw a rectangle on mousemove event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How do I draw a rectangle on an already drawn circle(hole) by using javascript in asp.net (C#). I have drawn my circle as a bitmap in the page. The rectangle should be drawn on the mousemove event.

Comment: you asked 5 question and only 1 get answerd,you should read jon skeet atricle--- http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: None of the answers are helping.

Answer (score 1):

Write the following code in img tag:

```
<img name="picture" src="Images/circle.jpg" alt="My Image"    
     onmouseover="document.picture.src=image2.src" 
     onmouseout="document.picture.src=image1.src" />
```

and the required javascript is :

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    image1 = new Image
    image1.src = "Images/circle.jpg"
    image2 = new Image
    image2.src = "Images/squre.jpg"
</script>
```